# Machine learning : RandomForest data pre-processing

Tags: machine-learning, preprocessor, random-forest

Before fitting a RandomForest what should be done with continuous features, should they be standard scaled?

Comment: standardscaled? Is that even a valid term in ML?

Answer (score 0):

No decision trees approach or Random Forests for that matter don't really care whether they are dealing with continuous data  or discrete data. So even if you don't standardize it wont be a issue.